# Creating individual pdf from excel table using macro VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word, mailmerge

I´m trying to complete my macro but I don´t know how to proceed mail merge from my prepared excel table (each row in my table = signle document). I wrote this macro but it doesn´t run. And the second thing is that the final document must be in pdf and I don´t know to adjust it.

```
Sub RunMerge()

    Dim wd As Object
    Dim wdocSource As Object

    Dim strWorkbookName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ArtSpecDatabase.docx")

    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

    wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

    wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
            Name:=strWorkbookName, _
            AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            Revert:=False, _
            Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"

    With wdocSource.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With

Dim PathToSave As String
PathToSave = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "docs" & "\" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value2 & ".docx"
'PathToSave = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\New folder (2)\docs\Merge_Mail_" & Replace(Replace(Now(), "/", "-"), ":", ".") & ".docx"
If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
Else
    wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 PathToSave, wdFormatDocumentDefault
End If

    wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set wdocSource = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How doesn't it run? Does it fail? If so, where? What version of Word and Excel are you using?

Comment: It runs, but I need to set an occurance. This macro creates just one document and I need one document of each rows. And second thing it saves documents as word .doc files not pdf. I´m using excel 2010

Comment: The macro creates word documents because you set the file name as ".docx" - should use the proper file extension. Additionally - if you want to create a document for each row, then you would have to loop through the rows and call the makro for each row.

Comment: Yes, I know but I don´t know how to adjust it...

Comment: @jean for the pdf export use  ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat ExportFormat:= wdExportFormatPDF , OutputFileName:="XXX" ; just a small hint - you can often record the step what you want to do and then use this snippet for your code

Answer (score 0):

You have MailMerge.Execute in your code, which should be generating a new Word document with a single section (can be one or more pages) for each record in the database. This is how Word is designed to do mail merge - there is no built-in functionality to create separate documents.

If you need that, then you either need to NOT use mail merge (there are other techniques for creating individual documents for a set of data) or you need to break up the resulting document. This has been discussed many times over the last twenty years and there are various ways to go about it. One is described here and uses Word's SubDocument feature:
http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/MergFram.htm

Another approach is presented here:
http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm